# SQL STUFF statement wrong order

Tags: sql, merge, sql-server-2012, duplicate-data

When I use the STUFF statement to merge rows, it sorts them alphabetically and numerically which causes the values to rearrange in an undesired order.
How do I prevent this from happening.

```
   STUFF ((SELECT '; ' + t2.[film name]
        FROM [filmbase].[dbo].[filmstowatch] t2
        WHERE t1.[Mobile Number] = t2.[Mobile Number]
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1,2,'') [film name],

   STUFF ((SELECT '; ' + t2.[customer No]
        FROM [filmbase].[dbo].[filmstowatch] t2
        WHERE t1.[Mobile Number] = t2.[Mobile Number]
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1,2,'') [customer no]
FROM temp.dbo.Temptable t1
```

For example,

**Original data:**

Customer No:-1

Film Name:- Fast & Furious

Mobile Number:- 123456789

Customer No:-2

Film Name:- 2 Fast 2 Furious

Mobile Number:- 123456789

Customer No:-3

Film Name:- Fast & Furious Tokyo Drift

Mobile Number:- 123456789

**Actual Output**:

```
Mobile Number:- 123456789, 
Film Name:- 2 Fast 2 Furious; Fast & Furious; Fast & Furious Tokyo Drift
Customer No:- 1;2;3
```

**Desired Output**:

```
Mobile Number:- 123456789, 
Film Name:- 2 Fast 2 Furious; Fast & Furious; Fast & Furious Tokyo Drift
Customer No:- 2;1;3
```

I want the film name to match the customer number in the order that the film name is presented in desired output example.

I'm thinking the code should be something like

```
STUFF ((SELECT '; ' + t2.[film name]
        FROM [filmbase].[dbo].[filmstowatch] t2
        WHERE t1.[Mobile Number] = t2.[Mobile Number]
order by film_name /* and then here should be something that matches film name to customer no??*/
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1,2,'') [film name],
```

To get 2F2F,f&f,f&fTD, 2,1,3
INSTEAD i get 2F2F,f&f,f&fTD, 1,2,3 which is what I don't want.

Comment: The `STUFF` statement doesn't do any reordering. If you want an order add an `order by` to your `xml path` queries.

Comment: I'm not sure if you know what I wanted but basically after writing the script I wanted to return in to one row: Mobile number, film names and customer number. where film names and customer names have their respective values of: 2f2f = 2, f&f=1, f&fTD = 3 ...instead I get 2f2f=1, f&f=2, f&fTD=3

Answer (score 1):

Add an `order by` to the subquery to get the ordering you want.  For instance, for a random ordering:

```
STUFF((SELECT '; ' + t2.[film name]
       FROM [filmbase].[dbo].[filmstowatch] t2
       WHERE t1.[Mobile Number] = t2.[Mobile Number]
       ORDER BY NEWID()
       FOR XML PATH('')
      ), 1, 2, ''
     ) as [film name],
```

I cannot tell from the question the ordering that you actually want.

Comment: I wanted to show that 2 fast 2 furious = 2 and fast & furious = 1 and fast and furious tokyo drift = 3

Comment: but instead the script has placed 2f2f, f&f, f&fTD with the order of 1;2;3 when it should be 2f2f, f&f, f&fTD with the order of 2;1;3